# Return data from the database instead of api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I change this action to Retrieve data from database instead of API
i want to Retrieve  data from database in SQL and show it in html input elements >>>>

```
public JsonResult getFromApi(string n)
{
   ApInvoker inv = new ApInvoker(n);
   var student = inv.getStd();
   if (student == null)
   {
      return Json(new { error = "لا يمكن الوصول للخادم , تحقق من اتصال الانترنت" });
   }
   StudentDTO sm = new StudentDTO();
   if (student.id == 0)
   {
      return Json(new { error = "لم يتم العثور على البيانات" });
   }
   sm.NID = Convert.ToString(student.nId);
   sm.FristName = student.name.Split(' ')[0];
   sm.FatherName = student.name.Split(' ')[1];
   sm.GrandFatherName = student.name.Split(' ')[2];
   sm.SureName = student.name.Split(' ')[3];
   sm.DateOfBirth = student.birthDate;
   sm.Address = student.address;
   sm.PlaeceOfBirth = student.plcOBirth;

   return Json(sm);
}
```

Comment: Well first, you'll need to have to know the connections to the database (`IP` , `Path` , `Credentials`, etc). The code you posted shows only how you are invoking the API and getting the data from the API. The supplied code has nothing to do with returning data from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Controller:**
     Make sure you created and inherited DbContext in model and also added Dbset of your 
        table to it.

```
    public ActionResult getFromDataBase()
    {
       // create object for your context of Database
        var studentContext = new studentContext();
       // return tablename data you want to retrieve in view
        return View(studentContext.TableName.ToList());

    }
```

**In View:**
        First import model
        @model ProjectName.Models.TableName       //e.g Demo.Models.StudentMaster

```
    //Now you can access any content using HTML tag helpers with loop or condition in view

    //e.g. Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.FieldName)
```